# The type org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, maven, dbeaver

```
 I am compling dbeaver-7.2.2 on mips64el platform using the command "mvn package  -DskipTests=true". it fails and displays error as follws:
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-compiler-plugin:1.7.0:compile (default-compile) on project org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /root/dbeaver-7.2.2/plugins/org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui/src/org/jkiss/dbeaver/ui/properties/PropertyTreeViewer.java:
[ERROR] /*
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] The type org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
[ERROR] /root/dbeaver-7.2.2/plugins/org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui/src/org/jkiss/dbeaver/ui/properties/PropertyTreeViewer.java:[1101]
[ERROR] private class SortListener implements Listener {
[ERROR] ^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] Listener cannot be resolved to a type
[ERROR] /root/dbeaver-7.2.2/plugins/org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui/src/org/jkiss/dbeaver/ui/properties/PropertyTreeViewer.java:[1173]
[ERROR] class PaintListener implements Listener {
[ERROR] ^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] Listener cannot be resolved to a type
[ERROR] 3 problems (3 errors)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui

the class PaintListener belogs to org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.mips64el which has been compiled successfully.i have set org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.mips64el classpath ,but it stills fail.

  dbeaver-7.2.2 source code:https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/releases/tag/7.2.2
```

[ERROR] The type org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

the class PaintListener belogs to org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.mips64el which has been compiled successfully.i have set org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.mips64el classpath ,but it stills fail.

Comment: What do you mean by _"i have set org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.mips64el classpath"_? Both, the plugin/bundle `org.eclipse.swt` and the fragment `org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.mips64el` have to be in the target platform and the Tycho build has to be configured to build `gtk.linux.mips64el`.

Comment: the class PaintListener belongs to org.eclipse. swt. gtk. linux. mips64el，so i guess the error occurs because of the dbeaver couldn't find the org.swt. eclipse. gtk. linux. mipe64el jar. so i  set org. eclipse. swt. gtk. linux. mips64el jar classpath for org.jkiss.dbeaver. ui can find the class PaintListener.

Comment: The log says it's a [Maven Tycho build](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html) to build the `org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui` Eclipse plugin (OSGi bundle), not a build for a plain Java project.

Comment: i built dbeaver on linux environment not windows，and org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui is a plugin of dbeaver not eclipse

Comment: and it is not a plain java project, but a maven project.

Comment: dbeaver is an Eclipse RCP. The log clearly shows it is using [tag:tycho] to build the RCP - see`org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-compiler-plugin` in the log.

Comment: As greg-440 already said, [dbeaver](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver) is an Eclipse-based application ([RCP](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Rich_Client_Platform)). Therefore some basic OSGi/Eclipse knowledge is required here, since it's not a plain Java application with a flat classpath built with Maven. In OSGi/Eclipse, bundles/plugins can be started and stopped at runtime and the dependencies are specified in the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file (since they also have to be resolved at runtime). Did you created `org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.mips64el` by you own, including porting of the SWT C code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.